# how to crawl this ajax website with taking results

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, python-2.7, scrapy

there is this website

http://www.dubailand.gov.ae/English/pages/Daily-Transactions.aspx

if you select a date and clicked search, then go to the **Daily Unit Transaction** you will get the results.

I wanted to get the results from scrapy. In other words, do the ajax call from scrapy.

I did this:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.dubailand.gov.ae/English/pages/Daily-Transactions.aspx']
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
        return Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'cookiejar': 1})

    def parse (self, response):
          return [FormRequest(url="http://www.dubailand.gov.ae/English/pages/Daily-Transactions.aspx",
                    formdata={'ctl00$ctl69$g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873$txtDate': '30/07/2015', 'id' : 'ctl00_ctl69_g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873_ntbSearch'},
                    callback=self.page_parse,
                    meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']},
                    method='POST', headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'X-MicrosoftAjax' : 'Delta=true',
                    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate'}
                    )]
    def page_parse(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        import json
        with open('data.html', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(response.body, outfile)
        #inspect_response(response)
        pass
```

i enabled the cookies, and did the ajax call. i checked the headers of the request using google chrome f12, and i added these parameters to the header.

but yet, the result is the main page **before clicking** the search button.

what mistake did i do please?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing some additional required headers and form params.

If you go to Chrome's network tab, right click the Daily-Transactions.aspx request, and select "Copy as cURL", you get the following command (I added newlines to make it easier to read):

```
curl
    "http://www.dubailand.gov.ae/English/pages/Daily-Transactions.aspx"
    -H "Cookie: _gat=1; ReadSpeakerSettings=enlarge=enlargeoff; _ga=GA1.3.469029184.1438564062; __zlcmid=W2eqfhsJvJwJFB; WSS_FullScreenMode=false"
    -H "Origin: http://www.dubailand.gov.ae"
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
    -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"
    -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    -H "Accept: */*"
    -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"
    -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"
    -H "Connection: keep-alive"
    -H "X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true"
    -H "Referer: http://www.dubailand.gov.ae/English/pages/Daily-Transactions.aspx"
    --data "ctl00"%"24ScriptManager=ctl00"%"24ctl69"%"24g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873"%"24pnlUpdate"%"7Cctl00"%"24ctl69"%"24g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873"%"24ntbSearch&_wpcmWpid=&wpcmVal=&MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource=&MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId=&MSOTlPn_View=0&MSOTlPn_ShowSettings=False&MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary=&MSOGallery_FilterString=&MSOTlPn_Button=none&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__REQUESTDIGEST=0x308F37DAA08525D735F224FEC60294E8FAF5A7EA8995A9C50DAAF8BF58C40A1C4DB1B09B26C2ED5C6EB93603D43549D8FD5590FBC4FCCAB1CC3D1AEA5DA431D8"%"2C03"%"20Aug"%"202015"%"2001"%"3A09"%"3A24"%"20-0000&MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName=Browse&MSOSPWebPartManager_ExitingDesignMode=false&MSOWebPartPage_Shared=&MSOLayout_LayoutChanges=&MSOLayout_InDesignMode=&_wpSelected=&_wzSelected=&MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName=Browse&MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName=false&MSOSPWebPartManager_EndWebPartEditing=false&__LASTFOCUS=&_maintainWorkspaceScrollPosition=0&__VIEWSTATE="%"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"%"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"%"2F"%"2F"%"2F"%"2F"%"2FD2QFPmN0bDAwJGN0bDY5JGdfNmZmYWRhM2FfMmNiY180M2EwXzkwMzRfZjQ4YTg2NGE4ODczJGdyZFZpZXdVbml0DzwrAAwBCGZkBT9jdGwwMCRjdGw2OSRnXzZmZmFkYTNhXzJjYmNfNDNhMF85MDM0X2Y0OGE4NjRhODg3MyRncmRWaWV3QmxkbmcPPCsADAEIZmQFUWN0bDAwJGN0bDY5JGdfOTAyMjkxNGVfODQwZl80NzZjXzgzYThfNTNhZDRhNTFiNGMzJGx2TWFpbkNhdGVnb3JpZXMkY3RybDAkbHZMaW5rcw8UKwAOZGRkZGRkZBQrAANkZGQCA2RkZGYC"%"2F"%"2F"%"2F"%"2F"%"2Fw9kBT5jdGwwMCRjdGw2OSRnXzZmZmFkYTNhXzJjYmNfNDNhMF85MDM0X2Y0OGE4NjRhODg3MyRncmRWaWV3TGFuZA88KwAMAQhmZA3Q4oZ3a"%"2B92Cd50AyWMNB"%"2BzZ"%"2Bx8Od"%"2FIdEKgSKHDgVTC&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=BAB98CB3&__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0&__SCROLLPOSITIONY=0&__EVENTVALIDATION="%"2FwEdABCCxEPo2yov8gXTDMAr0HjTMTZk9qLGncDjImqxppn1M"%"2F7gS7wH"%"2BvpamDGfzy44XjyxkHzOu"%"2FxxyB7As77WBg8gEdMiJi30Yb"%"2FSJbq8IdHRHbd"%"2BxSrwqnSzovEFhJ6JjNMPhWvp97LZaEb1vZ0oO794R4wg9ONQreMC"%"2B8UcJgrQpzPbDgjSZtU9BtyCPpwiGzX87ucANZWdjHKJz"%"2FK3OhlwlY0P5F8PFJvhxERQ"%"2Bz36ey293w7ajGDIYPfB9mELN3R6jWtt8"%"2Ft9xwUMGjMceqnsbVLrcbnqRUQF149eGC5OSkZ3vsVDiMzw"%"2BNbVY6xij"%"2FIXiqU9Dl4X6SIpJKVjRYzpK8uLqTW"%"2BY9ph7yJUlgmkbIBXgM9IDgmfbKUbP8pZlSk"%"3D&ctl00"%"24g_d71fd21b_67c9_47e2_85a5_f9f47d9715b8"%"24hdnPollID=1&ctl00"%"24ctl69"%"24g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873"%"24ddlProcedure=11&ctl00"%"24ctl69"%"24g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873"%"24txtDate=10"%"2F01"%"2F2015&__ASYNCPOST=true&ctl00"%"24ctl69"%"24g_6ffada3a_2cbc_43a0_9034_f48a864a8873"%"24ntbSearch=Search"
    --compressed
```

If I run this curl command, I get the proper response back, and if I change this bit:

```
txtDate=10"%"2F01"%"2F2015
```

To:

```
txtDate=11"%"2F01"%"2F2015
```

Then I get the next day's worth of data.

Since they're using ASP.net and it's not a public API that others are meant to integrate with you are stuck duplicating all the crufty/weird parameters that the site is sending as part of the AJAX request. For one thing, ASP.net uses this "view state" idea, where the entire session is stored client side and included in every request. This is why the form data is so large and obnoxious looking.

Another thing to watch out for, if your requests suddenly stop working, is if they set an expiration on the session. You may need to make a new GET request to `/Daily-Transactions.aspx` to get a new session.

Try adding all of the headers and form params to your scrapy request and it should work.

One final thing, it looks like you are using `json` in your `page_parse` method, but the data returned by this call is not JSON. It is a "partial" HTML document, so you'll need to parse that HTML for the data you're looking for.